# upgrade problem in lubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I am using lubuntu on my netbook.system ask me to upgrade last night and when the upgrade finished ı can only see the mouse arrow on the screen ı can not see any images of dekstop  ı can open lx terminal can you help me

Comment: Does your netbook have a Nvidia chip?

Answer (score 0):

That happened to my system also and so long as the HDD light isn't flickering I issued a `SUDO REBOOT` command to reset and see if everything had updated properly and worked ok, failing that I was going to re-install...